# Prove the index related problem about group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

$H$ is the subgroup with index $2$ of group $G$.
Prove: for any element $a \in G $ $$a^{2} \in H$$

and what if the index of $H$ is $3$? Can we derive that for any $a \in G $ $$a^{3} \in H$$

Comment: What have you tried? If you tell us this then we will be better able to help you. And it helps us feel that we are not just doing your homework for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I type it on my phone, so it's a bit difficult to express all my idea.  I'll try next time;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first question, consider the cosets. There are only two: $H$ and $G - H$. Recall that multiplication by $a$ permutes the cosets. Either it fixes them, or it swaps them. In either case, permuting them twice keeps them where they are. In other words, $a^2$ fixes the cosets. This implies $a^2 H = H$, and so $a^2 \in H$.

For cases $n > 2$, this is false, because there is more freedom in the permutations. We can construct an example for all $n$ if we really want to. I'm not sure it's the simplest one, but it's the best I can come up with.

Pick the largest prime $p < n$. Let $G = S_n$, $H = \langle (12 \ldots p) \rangle$ and $x = (23 \ldots (p+1))$. Then $|G : H| = \frac{n!}{p}$, and $x$ has order $p$. Since $H$ and $\langle x \rangle$ are of prime order and distinct, they must intersect trivially. But $\frac{n!}{p}$ isn't divisible$^\ast$ by $p$, so $x^p \ne e$. So $x^p \notin H$.

---

$^\ast$There's always a prime between $k$ and $2k$, so if $n!$ has two factors of $p$, you can pick a prime between $p$ and $2p$.

Answer (score 0):

If $a \in H$, then $a^2 \in H$ since $H$ is closed. If not, then $a \in a^{-1}H$ because $H\cup a^{-1}H = G$, thus: $a = a^{-1}h$. So: $a^2 = a\cdot a= aa^{-1}h = eh = h \in H$. So $a^2 \in H$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $|G:H|=2$ then $H$ must be normal so $G/H$ is a group of order $2$ which means $a^2H=H$ for any $a\in G$ which concludes the result.

In general if $|G:H|=n$ and $H$ is normal then $a^n\in H$. When $H$ is not normal this may fail,

Let $G=S_3$ and $H=<(1,2)>$ then $|G:H|=3$ but $x^3\notin H$ where $x=<(2,3)>$.